# C# Lists - do I use Class Methods (Get/ Set etc) again once the data is in a list?

Tags: c#, list, get, set, instance

A quick question on OOP. I am using a list together with a class and class constructor.  So I use the class constructor to define the data set and then add each record to my list as the user creates them.

My questions is once the data is in the list and say I want to alter something is it good practice to find the record, create an instance using that record and then use my class methods to do whatever needs doing - and then put it back in the list?

For example below I have my class with constructor.  Lets say I only want the system to release strCode if the Privacy field is set to public.  Now just using Instances I would use for example Console.WriteLine(whateverproduct.ProductCode)  but if the record is already in a list do i take it out of the list - create an instance and then use this method?

```
class Product
{
    private String strCode;
    private Double dblCost;
    private Double dblNet;
    private String strPrivacy;


    public Product(String _strCode, Double _dblCost, Double _dblNet, String _strPrivacy)
    {
        strCode = _strCode;
        dblCost = _dblCost;
        dblNet = _dblNet;
        strPrivacy = _strPrivacy;
    }

    public string ProductCode
    {
        get
        {
            if (strPrivacy == "Public")
            {
                return strCode;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Product Private Can't release code";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to edit a record inside your list, and after all is done, you want to put it back into?

Comment: yeah - I know I can do it directly in the list but I'm assuming best practice is to use my class methods to do whatever I need to do....or maybe not thats what im checking

Comment: Can you provide a little example, so understanding is a little easier for me? :)

Comment: Can you give a little code example? I do not have a clue what you mean.

Comment: have added some code hopefully it explains what i mean

Comment: What does "record" mean? Is that a reference to an instance of Product that's in the list or the strCode itself?

Comment: a record would be (code, cost, net, privacy). for example there might be 100 products stored in a list (each with its own code, cost,net privacy).

Comment: So you answered your own question. You store Products => you look up Products => you use Product's getters ... am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score -1):

Lets say we have the following:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    private string _test = "Some constant value at this point";

    public string GetTest()
    {
        return _test;
    }

    public void SetTest()
    {
        //Nothing happens, you aren't allow to alter it. 
        //_test = "some constant 2";
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Test> listOfTest = new List<Test>()
        {
            new Test() {Id = 0, Name = "NumberOne", Amount = 1.0M},
            new Test() {Id = 1, Name = "NumberTwo", Amount = 2.0M}
        };

        Test target = listOfTest.First(x => x.Id == 0);

        Console.WriteLine(target.Name);

        target.Name = "NumberOneUpdated";

        Console.WriteLine(listOfTest.First(x => x.Id == 0).Name);

        Console.WriteLine(listOfTest.First(x => x.Id == 0).GetTest());//This will alsways be "Some constant value at this point";


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Technically you could do away with the SetTest method entirely. However, I included it to demonstrate, what it would look like, if you wanted to alter _test.

You don't want to ever create a new instance of a class, you already have an instance of. you can just alter the class where it is allowed by the author of the class, where you need to. And keep that class reference for as long as you need it. Once you are done, the reference will be garbage collected, once the program finds no active reference to your object(instance).

Comment: @Fildor In the context of this question.

Comment: @Fildor Except that it was written in an answer, to a specific question. And an answer only to this context. ..

Comment: @Fildor No. Ever, even outside this context, breaks that.
Like any math problem it is always within the parameters given in the question, or any answer loses all relevance, immediately.